# String Tokenizer, delimiter

Tags: java, string, tokenize

I am using this code:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer=new StringTokenizer(line, "::");
```

to split the following String:

```
hi my name is visghal:: what is yor name name:: being thw simple my::: what is yor name name.
```

Now i want to split the string using `::` as delimiter. It is working fine. But it is also taking `:::` into consideration.

In other words i want:

```
hi my name is visghal
what is yor name name
being thw simple my
: what is yor name name
```

Instead it is giving me the following:

```
being thw simple my 
what is yor name name   
hi my name is visghal
```

It is taking `::` and `:::` as same. Is there any means to avoid this?

Comment: StringTokenizer is deprecated, avoid it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use String#split like this:

```
String[] arr = str.split("::");
```

**EDIT:**

```
String[] arr = str.split("::\\s*"); // for stripping spaces after ::
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hi my name is visghal
what is yor name name
being thw simple my
: what is yor name name
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) if you need additional functionality over `String.split`. It will allow for trimming and omitting empty strings.

```
 String myInput = "...";
 Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on("::").split(myInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is taking :: and ::: as same

No, your delimeter `::` is found twice in this string part `:::` and this is the explanation for your result.

You should use `split("::")` method.